# How to get the natural parameter of Pareto distribution if $\beta$ is fixed?

Tags: density-function, exponential-family, pareto-distribution

With $\beta$ known, $f_\alpha(y)=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}(\frac{\beta}{y})^{\alpha+1}=e^{\ln\alpha-\ln\beta+(\alpha+1)\ln\beta-(\alpha+1)\ln y}$. Now the problem is should we expand $-(\alpha+1)\ln y$ and claim natural parameter is $-\alpha$ or do we simply say it's $-(\alpha +1)$?